# While displaying image in image tag, sometimes I am not getting image from azure blob storage due to the non-successful upload

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, image, azure-blob-storage

I am using the Azure blob container to upload and download images. And using below method I am trying to upload the image in storage client

```
    UploadBlob(string strContainerName, string BlobName, string strContentType, Stream FileStream)
    {
        try
        {
            if (InitializeStorage(strContainerName))
            {
                CloudBlobContainer container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference(strContainerName);
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(BlobName);
                blob.Properties.ContentType = strContentType;
                blob.UploadFromStream(FileStream);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and from html page I am sending the base64string image and handles like below code in which I am converting to byte array then to stream and as follows:

```
            string newstrImage = updobj.Image.Replace("data:;base64,/", "/");

            byte[] imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(newstrImage);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
            string fileName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var imgurl = string.Empty;

            var imgdata = BlobUtility.UploadBlob("triplecourtimages",fileName, "image/png", stream);
            if (imgdata)
                imgurl = BlobUtility.GetBlobUrl("triplecourtimages", fileName);
```

But when I am trying to retrieve the image url which was saved in my DB sometimes it doesn't show any image. At that time I used to check the blob container and found the image size is 0 bytes.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> The base64string image uploaded from html page

As far as I know, the base64string image should looks like as follows:

data:image/[png,jpg,jpeg,etc.];base64,[Base64-encoded binary content of the image]

Please try to modify your back-end code

`string newstrImage =Regex.Replace(updobj.Image,"^data:image/(png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif);base64,",string.Empty);`
Instead of

`string newstrImage = updobj.Image.Replace("data:;base64,/", "/");`

> Files are uploaded successfully to Azure Blob, but sometimes the blob(image) size is 0 bytes

1.Please make sure the `updobj.Image` you get is not empty
You could log the details about the uploaded base64-encoded image content.

2.Please make sure the position property of your stream for uploading is set to zero. After you construct the MemoryStream, you could add the following code behind it.
Sample:

`var stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Here is code sample on my side, you could follow and find whether it could help you.

**ImageUpload.js**

```html
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("FileUploadCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.fileInfo = {};
    var fileSelect = document.createElement("input");
    fileSelect.type = "file";
    $scope.UploadFile = function () {
        fileSelect.click();
    }
    fileSelect.onchange = function () {
        var file = fileSelect.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function (e) {
            $scope.fileInfo.Base64 = e.target.result;
            $scope.$apply();
            //print log
            console.log($scope.fileInfo.Base64);
            //upload the file
            $.post("/Home/UploadFile", {
                base64Image: $scope.fileInfo.Base64
            }, function(data) {
                alert("Upload file with result:" + data);
            });
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

**HomeController.cs**

```html
public JsonResult UploadFile(string base64Image)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string newstrImage = Regex.Replace(base64Image, "^data:image/(png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif);base64,", string.Empty);
        byte[] imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(newstrImage);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string fileName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var imgurl = string.Empty;
        var imgdata = BlobUtility.UploadBlob("triplecourtimages", fileName, "image/png", stream);
if (imgdata)
  imgurl = BlobUtility.GetBlobUrl("triplecourtimages", fileName);
        result = string.Format("Upload successfully,image path:\r\n{0}", imgurl);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = string.Format("Error:{0}", ex.Message);
    }
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

Additionally, you could use the following online tools to convert your images:

Base64 To Image: http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
Image To Base64: http://codebeautify.org/image-to-base64-converter